# I want to be able to insert data from forms in two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been trying to insert data from form in two tables but I didn't get lucky, and the last I have tried got the first table inserted but the second table is empty and nothing inserted to it, below is my query code:

```
$query1=mysql_query("INSERT INTO $Tname (tnumber2, results, idate, iaddress, tstatus, saddress, scountry, ddate, daddress) VALUES('$tnumber2','$results','$idate','$iaddress','$tstatus','$saddress','$scountry','$ddate','$daddress')");
$id = mysql_insert_id();
$query2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO $UPname (tnumber2, pdate, act, paddress, up) VALUES('$tnumber2','$pdate','$act','$paddress','$up')");
```

I am getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update (tnumber2, pdate, act, paddress, up) VALUES('59644039299744','59644039299' at line 1

Comment: You're getting `$id` from your first query, but not doing anything with it in the second. I'd suggest adding calls to `mysql_error()` to see if there are any errors being returned by the database.

Comment: here is the error...........You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update (tnumber2, pdate, act, paddress, up) VALUES('59644039299744','59644039299' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update (...

it looks like your table is called `update`

That's a reserved word in SQL, so it's generating an error.

If possible, you should rename the table, as using reserved words as table or column names is confusing; but if that's not feasible, you can escape the name with backticks; try this as your second SQL call:

```
INSERT INTO `$UPname` (tnumber2, pdate, act, paddress, up) VALUES('$tnumber2','$pdate','$act','$paddress','$up')");
```

I'll also add the compulsory warning that `mysql_` functions are deprecated, and you should switch to mysqli_ or PDO - they both help you write safer code. Also, if you're going to be using variables for table names, you need to be make sure that you're validating them very, very well.

Comment: thanks so much i got what am looking for now